# Python & Matplotlib: Simplify plot configuration (xlabel, title, legend...)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I make plots, I always need to set x,ylabels, titles, legend etc. Setting them one by one is tedious, so I tried to put them into a single helper method:

```
def plt_configure(ax=None, xlabel='', ylabel='', title='', legend=False, tight=False, figsize=False):
    if ax == None :
        ax=plt.gca()
        plt.suptitle(title)
    else:
        ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    if legend:
        if isinstance(legend, dict):
            ax.legend(**legend)
        else:
            ax.legend()
    if tight:
        if tight == 'xtight' or tight == 'x':
            ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
        elif tight == 'ytight':
            ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
        else:
            ax.axis('tight')
    if figsize:
        plt.gcf().set_size_inches(figsize)
```

So it can be used like

```
# Use Case 1
plt_configure(xlabel='Direction', ylabel='Difference with ECDF', 
              legend={'loc':'best'},figsize=(8,2.5))
# Use Case 2
plt_configure(title='Direction Distribution Comparison',
              xlabel='Direction',ylabel='Frequency', legend={'loc': 'best'} ,tight='xtight',figsize = (8,2.5))
```

I want to know if there is a more elegant way to do this? (Define the xlabel, title more efficiently then setting them one by one)

Also, the helper method that I made looks quite complex and long. Is there anyway to simply it?

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, I am also used to set up a helper function for `plt` setup. I feel like only setting the very basics in such kind of a function is sufficient, as the rest is always plot-dependent.

You only run into the high complexity of your "helper", because you try to put too much options into it, essentially making it harder to control and less clear than just directly setting the desired options for each plot.

This is the one I use:

```
def plt_setup(width=8, height=6, borders='lb', fontsize=9):
    font = {
        'family' : 'Roboto',
        'weight' : 'light',
        'size'   : int(fontsize)
    }
    matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

    plt.figure(figsize=(float(width), float(height)))

    ax = plt.subplot(111)

    for b in ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom']:
        if b[0] in borders:
            ax.spines[b].set_visible(True)
            ax.spines[b].set_linewidth(.6)
        else:
            ax.spines[b].set_visible(False)

    ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
    ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
```

Once the plot basics are set, I control the rest individually for each plot. If you have to create similar plots all over and want to keep things slim while writing plot code, you may want to go for additional functions that handle different plot types each.

A very rough start (far from complete) could look something like this:

```
def plt_barchart(df, op=dict()):
    plt_setup()
    # Set options according to values in op-dict
    # (just a few exemplary settings here...)
    if 'title' in op.keys():
        plt.title(op['title'])
    plt.xticks(df['x'].values, df['labels'].values)
    # Get amount of bar groups
    ycols = [k for k in df.keys().values if k not in ['x', 'labels']]
    if 'position' in op.keys() and op['position'] == 'dodge':
        # Calculate x offset and bar width depending on group count
        barwidth = .8 / len(ycols)
    # ...
```

Comment: Along the lines of what I do in my helper. Slight difference is that I have the helper arranged as a separate python module, which I import in my client script. All the plot parameters that I want to have the option of changing from default I have as globals (or you could make class members if you don't like globals). I have accessors to these parameters or you can just refer to them explicitly. I then have several different plot functions.
By doing this I have hidden all references to MATPLOTLIB from the client code.

Comment: @PeterBingham Is there any example I can see?

Comment: This has some issues (I just hack changes in) but it's my helper module and might give you some ideas. Some of the parameters are globals (at the top) and some are function parameters but you could make everything global depending on your usage needs: https://github.com/petersbingham/ProtoQScat/blob/master/utilities/general/simpplot.py

Comment: I should add that I've ended up with several of these helper modules, depending on very different use cases. I've one that will allow control of subplot and another for a real time updating chart using the low level API. Always found MATPLOTLIB quite cumbersome, hence my need for these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to achieve the above.

For example, let's say we have 3 subplots and we need to have common legends, labels, `xscale` or `yscale` etc.

```
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(9,10))

ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(131)
ax1.scatter(data_z,data_zphot1,s=3,marker='.')
ax1.annotate(r'$0.001\times(1+z_{c})$',xy=(0.05,0.8),xycoords=('axes fraction'),fontsize=12)

ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(132)
ax2.scatter(data_z,data_zphot2,s=3,marker='.')
ax2.annotate(r'$0.005\times(1+z_{c})$',xy=(0.05,0.8),xycoords=('axes fraction'),fontsize=12)

ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(133)
ax3.scatter(data_z,data_zphot3,s=3,marker='.')
ax3.annotate(r'$0.010\times(1+z_{c})$',xy=(0.05,0.8),xycoords=('axes fraction'),fontsize=12)

for ax in [ax1,ax2,ax3]:
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    ax.set_xlim(0.0,3.5)
    ax.set_ylim(0.0,4.5)
```

So inside the `for` loop by calling all the `axes` one by one, a common template can be achieved for all your subplots.

And if all the 3 subplots need a common `x label` and `y label`, it can be done by:

```
fig2.text(0.5,0.02,'x label here',ha='center',fontsize=22)
fig2.text(0.02,0.5,'y label here',va='center',rotation='vertical',fontsize=22)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I may mislead you into another direction. I'm just asking about how to set xlabel, title ... with fewer lines.